# How to solve $\text{d}B = A\land \text{d}A$ where $A$ and $B$ are differential forms?

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

Consider the form $2p+1$-form given by: $\omega_A = A \land \mathrm{d}A$ for a certain $p$-form $A$. It easy to prove that it is a closed form: $\mathrm{d}\omega_A = \text{d}A \land \mathrm{d}A + (-1)^p \mathrm{d}^2A = 0$.

Assuming that $A$ is defined in convex set, the [Poincaré lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Poincar%C3%A9_lemma) guaranties that, there is a $2p-$form $\theta_A$ such that: $\mathrm{d}\theta_A = A\land \text{d}A.$

My question is how to explicitly compute the components of $\theta_A$. For example, for the case of $A$ being a 1-form: $\frac{1}{2!} \frac{\partial \theta_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^\sigma} = \frac{1}{3!} \epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma}_{\mu\nu\sigma} A_{\alpha}\frac{\partial A_{\gamma}}{\partial x^\beta}$, but, for me, it is not clear how to proceed from this point.

Comment: Do you know that $p$ is even? How are you concluding that $dA\wedge dA=0$ in general? This is false. Take $A = x\,dy + z\,dw$, for example.

Comment: @TedShifrin. You are absolutely right! I made a terrible mistake, and probably the question now does not make much sense!